# Undertow HTTPS listener

Tags: java, https, undertow

I'm trying to serve a simple 'Hello world!' response over HTTPS with self-signed certificate using Undertow embedded server. However I get `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` on the client (Chrome) and `SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common` in server logs.

It seems that additionally to `KeyManager[]` array I need to provide the TLS protocol to use, but I can not found where I should put it. Complete example is avaiable at https://github.com/isopov/undertow-https-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sopovs/moradanen/UndertowHttpsTest.java
 while at https://github.com/isopov/undertow-https-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sopovs/moradanen/JettyHttpsTest.java there is example of similar test using Jetty server (to prove that certificate is good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change to code worked for me:

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(getKeyManagers(), null, null);

    Undertow.builder().addHttpsListener(10443, "0.0.0.0", sslContext)...
```